# Creating a function that counts words and characters (Including punctuation, but excluding white space)

Tags: python

I need to make a function which counts number of characters (including punctuation and excluding white space) and words in a given phrase. I've created a function so far that can count the number of characters ,but it includes white space as well and does not count words. How can I exclude whitespace and implement counting words as well?

```
text = " If I compare myself to someone else, then I am playing a game 
I will never win. "
def count_chars_words(txt):
    chars = len(txt.replace(' ',''))
    words = len(txt.split(' '))
    return [words,chars]

print(count_chars_words(text))


output [19, 63]
```

Answer (score 1):

Count characters by stripping whitespaces from the text with `replace(' ','')`, and then getting the length of the string.

Count words by splitting the sentence into a list of words, and checking the length of the list.

Then, return both in a list.

```
text ="If I compare myself to someone else, then I am playing a game I will never win."
def count_chars_words(txt):
        chars = len(txt.replace(' ',''))
        words = len(txt.split(' '))
        return [words,chars]

print(count_chars_words(text))
```

Output:

```
[17, 63]
```

To get an idea of what `replace()` and `split()` do:

```
>> text.replace(' ','')
'IfIcomparemyselftosomeoneelse,thenIamplayingagameIwillneverwin.'
>> text.split(' ')
['If', 'I', 'compare', 'myself', 'to', 'someone', 'else,', 'then', 'I', 'am', 'playing', 'a', 'game', 'I', 'will', 'never', 'win.']
```

Comment: Wow never new about replace or split that is really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function `string.split()` might be useful for you! It can take a string, find every instance of whatever you feed into it (such as `" "`) and split your string into a list of each set of characters separated by `" "` (pretty much by word).  With this you should be able to continue!

`"If I compare myself to someone else, then I am playing a game I will never win.".split(" ")`

gives

`['If', 'I', 'compare', 'myself', 'to', 'someone', 'else,', 'then', 'I', 'am', 'playing', 'a', 'game', 'I', 'will', 'never', 'win.']`

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid counting whitespace, have you considered using an `if` statement? You might find [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) and the `in` operator useful here!

As for counting words, [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is your friend. In fact, if you split the words up first, is there a simple way to avoid even the `if` referenced above?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea and not the efficient way, if you need a good way to do that use regex:

```
text ="If I compare myself to someone else, then I am playing a game I will never win."

total_num = len(text)
spaces = len([s for s in text if s == ' '])
words = len([w for w in text.split()])

print('total characters = ', total_num)
print('words = ', words)
print('spaces=', spaces)
print('charcters w/o spaces = ', total_num - spaces)
```

output:

```
total characters =  79
words =  17
spaces= 16
charcters w/o spaces =  63
```

Edit: using regex the more efficient will be:

```
import re

chars_without_spaces = re.findall(r'[^\s]', text)  # charcters w/o spaces 
words = re.findall(r'\b\w+', text)  # words
```

Comment: Looping over the text twice is unnecessary here.

Comment: @glhr where is the looping here?

Comment: You have two list comprehensions.

Comment: yes, as i mentioned in top of my answer the whole thing is not efficient for text processing it is better to use regex